# How to force custom color scheme when using Inverted Colors in Evince?

Tags: colors, pdf, evince

As pointed out in [Software to read PDFs with inverted colors (Windows)](https://superuser.com/a/657846/261940), instead of having a very `white` on very `black` color scheme (which induces a very nasty contrast) it is often preferable to use a custom color scheme such as `light grey` on `dark grey` (which is much nicer on the eyes and reduces eyestrain when reading PDF documents on-screen).

When activating `View > Inverted Colors` in Evince, the programme will literally invert colors and generate the undesirable very `white` on very `black` color scheme. How can I configure Evince to instead replace colors with a `light grey` on `dark grey` color scheme?

(I know that Adobe Reader can do this, but I prefer using Evince in day-to-day usage.)

Comment: You can't, it's hardcoded in  `evince` (see [ev-document-misc.c](https://git.gnome.org/browse/evince/tree/libdocument/ev-document-misc.c)). The only way is to patch the source code.

Comment: What features from evince do you value? Have you tried okular? As a pdf reader, it works well with dark color variations and proper contrasts.

Answer (score 1):

#### Change the background color of evince to the light green and protect your eyes

Config the compile environment and dowload source

```
sudo apt source evince
```

Change the source to your color, such as the light green(R:199,G:237,B:204).
Edit the fuction **ev_document_misc_invert_surface** in file: **libdocument/ev-document-misc.c** at line 467

change

```
cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_DIFFERENCE);
cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1., 1., 1.);
```

to

```
cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_DARKEN);
cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.8, 0.9098, 0.8117647);
```

Config and make and make install

```
cd evince
./configure --prefix=$YOUR-PLACE  --enable-nls --disable-scrollkeeper --disable-dbus --disable-debug --disable-tests --disable-nautilus --disable-thumbnailer --disable-previewer --disable-comics --without-keyring --without-gconf --without-gtk-unix-print
```

Then make, and I get the error:

```
Making all in synctex
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/luopeng/Downloads/evince-3.28.4/cut-n-paste/synctex'
  CC       libsynctex_la-synctex_parser.lo
  CC       libsynctex_la-synctex_parser_utils.lo
synctex_parser_utils.c:106:29: error: format string is not a string literal [-Werror,-Wformat-nonliteral]
        result += vfprintf(stderr, reason, arg);
                                   ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
Makefile:545: recipe for target 'libsynctex_la-synctex_parser_utils.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [libsynctex_la-synctex_parser_utils.lo] Error 1
```

Of couse, fix it by:

```
pragma GCC diagnostic push
pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
    result = fprintf(stderr,"SyncTeX ERROR: ");
    result += vfprintf(stderr, reason, arg);
    result += fprintf(stderr,"\n");
pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

In the version of ubuntu18.04, I found seveal errors as the above case and
I fix them with the GCC ignored. **(please add # before the pragma in the following code)**

```
pragma GCC diagnostic push
pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
  the code where the errors occur
pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Then change the config in `/usr/share/applications/evince.desktop`

```
chang Exec=$YOUR-Evince-PLACE/bin/evince %U
```

When click the *view → Inverted Color*, your background color will change to light green.

**Enjoy it!**